# SignalR makes website hang when at least 2 people are connected

Tags: asp.net, signalr

SignalR works fine when one user is connected to the website but as soon as at least two people are connected to the website at the same time it takes more than a minute to load a page and it results in timeouts most of the time.

I have tried to disable SignalR and the problem is gone but as soon as I enable it the issue is back. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check the number of threads you have in your IIS process (I forget if it's AppPool or not), (Might not be the issue but without more information, it's hard to tell) you need about 12, if you do not have concurrent threads you are going to have issues like this.